# Flash CC Canvas HTML5 Element adding interactivity in Timeline

Tags: javascript, flash, button, html5-canvas, flash-cc

I've been trying to solve this for several time, but I'm now pointless with this situation. I'm creating a HTML5 canvas project in Flash CC, I'm kinda new in JS (not difficult BTW), the point is, I have around 10 keyframes inside my main timeline, and some classic buttons, all I need to do is to navigate inside every frame when a button is pressed (pretty easy uh!) the trouble is, the first frame works perfectly, but from 2 to the others, I can't be able to use buttons, interactivity is being programmed as follows:

```
var self = this;
this.stop();
this.btn4.addEventListener("click", clickUno);
function clickUno() {
    self.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated, I just don't know why 1st frame works great, but others doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with canvas with flash.

1. I needed to created completed new buttons on every instance you need a button to get code to work. (ODD I know.)
2. Button code.

   ```
   this.getinsideIt.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_9.bind(this));

   function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_9()
   {
       this.Mygreatmovie.gotoAndPlay(350);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need a button, clicking on which proceeds your animation 1 frame at a time. Correct?

You should make use of the currentFrame and totalFrames properties of the main stage for this. Query the current frame and move on to next!

```
var self = this;
this.stop();
if(!this.btn4.hasEventListener("click", clickUno))
    this.btn4.addEventListener("click", clickUno);
function clickUno(e) {
    var curr = self.currentFrame;
    var total = self.totalFrames;
    self.gotoAndStop((curr + 1)%total);
}
```